# Web ui Drag & drop designer

Tags: drag-and-drop

i know Ext Designer, but i cannot reach in time to take the demonstration period of it.

I think that on the internet will be a lot of Ext Designer like apps.

If someone knows a similar product (don't want dreamweaver or similar) can say me the name?

If there are open source would be better, but paid apps although will be OK

Thanks a lot for all, and I know that my English it's too poor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx), it has a good interface, can be run inside Firefox, and can export to HTML!

EDIT:
There is also [Axure](http://www.foreui.com/)

Also, you may try [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/)

Comment: I tried pencil but when i export on HTML (using a template) it exports an image of the work, not the fields like radio buttons and more

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/). It is free (even for commercial uses AFAIK), but contains only a subset of features of full blown Visual Studio.